# How to add UIView and cover entire screen

Tags: objective-c, xcode, autolayout

I am trying to add a gray uiview overlay using autolayouts so that when you rotate the device it automatically still covers the entire screen.  How would this be done programatically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is easy, you need 4 constraints to do that - top, bottom, left and right:

```
NSLayoutConstraint *topConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:superview attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop multiplier:1.0f constant:0.0f];
NSLayoutConstraint *bottomConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:superview attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom multiplier:1.0f constant:0.0f];
NSLayoutConstraint *leftConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeft relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:superview attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeft multiplier:1.0f constant:0.0f];
NSLayoutConstraint *rightConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeRight relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:superview attribute:NSLayoutAttributeRight multiplier:1.0f constant:0.0f];
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
UIView *greyView = [UIView new];
[self.view addSubview:greyView];
greyView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
NSDictionary *viewDictionary = @{@“greyView”:greyView};

[self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-0-[myView]-0-|“ options:0 metrics:nil views:viewDictionary]];

[self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@“H:|-0-[myView0]-0-|” options:0 metrics:nil views:viewDictionary]];
```